# file_get_contents not working

Tags: php, apache, file-get-contents

I am trying to read a file in with file_get_contents () - it's a remote HTTP file, and I've checked the URL and it's fine.  Only it doesn't work.

More to the point the the error message is the standard Firefox server error:

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset
>   while the page was loading.

... rather than any form of PHP error.  It also only took a couple of seconds to come back so it can't be hitting the script runtime limit - any ideas on what is going wrong here?

It's PHP 5 on Apache 2, running on Windows btw.

*To clarify it's my connection to my .php file that is having this issue.  Even if the remote file wasn't there I'd at least expect an error - that my webserver is apparently dropping the connection rather than at least giving an error message is the issue.*

*Update 2:  Same issue with fopen instead of file_get_contents*

Update 3: It may even be crashing the server:

```
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:21 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:21 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2720
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:21 2010] [notice] Child 2720: Child process is running
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:21 2010] [notice] Child 2720: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:21 2010] [notice] Child 2720: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:21 2010] [notice] Child 2720: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4912
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Child 4912: Child process is running
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Child 4912: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Child 4912: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:24 2010] [notice] Child 4912: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2560
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Child 2560: Child process is running
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Child 2560: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Child 2560: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:31 2010] [notice] Child 2560: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 712
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Child 712: Child process is running
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Child 712: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Child 712: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Mar 28 17:46:34 2010] [notice] Child 712: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Mar 28 17:49:19 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sun Mar 28 17:49:19 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Your host may be banned on that remote site.

Comment: Should file_get_contents not return an error then?  That is what is confusing me.  It also loads the file fine in my browser so that can't be it.

Comment: have you tried getting another file/page on another server?

Comment: To further explain Col. Shrapnel, "The connection was reset" does not necessarily mean that. What it really means is "the server dropped the connection."

Comment: There can be a firewall too. isn't it a local workstation from where you want to get this file?

Answer (score 0):

Use [cUrl](http://nl.php.net/curl) and make a connection by a proxy: CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL